# setPreferenceScreen() in static Settings fragment - Refresh Settings Activity

Tags: android, methods, static, fragment

I have change language option in my settings activity, and as suggested I created inner class fragment. Android Studio says that it must be static (inner fragment) and if its not it will crash (tested and happen'd). All the other methods in it have to be static and its working ok, except now I need

```
setPreferenceScreen(null);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

so it would restart preference for the changes in language to be shown. But, these 2 methods can't be in a static method and I'm putting them in preference change listener which has to be static! So is there any way around this???

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            bindSummaryValue(findPreference("pref_key_delay"));


    private static void bindSummaryValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
        listener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener listener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

            String mString = newValue.toString();
            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                ListPreference mListPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = mListPreference.findIndexOfValue(mString);
                preference.setSummary(index >= 0 ? mListPreference.getEntries()[index] : null);
            }
            else if (preference instanceof EditTextPreference) {
                preference.setSummary(mString);
            }

            return true;
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: Post your code.  We have no idea what you're actually doing, or may be doing wrong, without it.

Comment: @GabeSechan edited